# Entity Framework query slow when searching on concatenated fields

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When searching for a member registry in an application using Entity Framework where it needs to search on both first and last name (two different columns in the db, about 100k members), it gets slower than I think it needs to be (1-2 seconds):

```cs
query.Where(member => (member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName).Contains(searchValue));
```

When I try to do something equivalent with an sql query it is a lot faster (< 1 ms):

```sql
select * from [Members] where CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, LastName) like '%foo bar%'
```

Is there a better way to do this type of concatenation and search, that I've missed? I'm personally not very used to EF.

Comment: How about if you try `String.Concat`? `query.Where(member => String.Concat(member.FirstName, " " , member.LastName).Contains(searchValue));`

Comment: @SelimYıldız sadly it made no difference for me. Good idea though.

Comment: What version of EF?